# Dropbox webhook not notifying of delta

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to implement some simple webhooking in Dropbox and I am testing it out on heroku. The registration goes ok:

> https://guarded-escarpment-2793.herokuapp.com/dropbox Enabled

And the Dropbox app page gives the green light.

But **NOTHING** I do seems to trigger a post to this URL. 
I have:

- Added files
- Deleted files
- Modified files
- Created directories

All from within the desktop app and done some through the website.

I would have expected *something* here but I get the silent treatment.

- I verified the accounts and I have tried various app configuration scenarios (I have tried to give apps as much and as little rights as possible just hoping).

If I use a REST client to just post some data I get:

> [32m2015-07-20T19:49:31.241274+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info
>   method=POST pa h="/dropbox" host=guarded-escarpment-2793.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=af539fdc-614
>   -48a5-b05d-fb25184b3f53 fwd="98.237.205.126" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=201 bytes=136

So, I know POST is actually making it to my app successfully. How to I actually trigger this?

Here is my Java code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        port(Integer.valueOf(System.getenv("PORT")));
        staticFileLocation("/public");

        get("/dropbox", (req, res) -> req.queryParams("challenge"));
        post("/dropbox", (request, response) -> {
                    response.status(201);
                    return "dropbox post received";
                }

        );  

    }


}
```

Comment: Has the account you're  making changes in linked the API app?

Comment: I don't understand. I added the webhook URL to the app console

Comment: Dropbox webhook notifications only notify you of changes in accounts of users who have authorized your API app to connect to their accounts. Your API app should implement the OAuth flow to let users connect the app to their account: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauthguide

Comment: There we go! That's was the missing sauce. If you would like to Post it as an answer I will give you credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dropbox webhook notifications](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/webhooks) only notify you of changes in accounts of users who have authorized your API app to connect to their accounts.

Your API app should implement the OAuth flow to let users connect the app to their account:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauthguide

Once they do, any changes in their accounts will result in your registered webhook URI being notified.